# Primefaces SelectManyMenu Converter not Converting

Tags: jsf, primefaces, converters, selectmanymenu

I am using a converter throughout my system which uses the following annotation:

```
@FacesConverter(forClass = Group.class)
```

this works fine except for SelectManyMenu where the conversion doesn't seem to take place. My SelectManyMenu is defined as follows

```
<p:selectManyMenu value="#{maintainMB.filteredLogicalGroups}" var="g" showCheckbox="true">  
<f:selectItems value="#{maintainMB.logicalGroupFilterList}" var="group" itemLabel="#{group.name}" itemValue="#{group}" />  

<p:column>  
    <p:graphicImage value="image.png.xhtml" width="32"/>
</p:column>  

<p:column>  
    #{g.name} 
</p:column>  
</p:selectManyMenu>
```

The SelectMenyMenu renders ok but when i select items they are returned as a string not an object.

If i change my Converter annotation to

```
@FacesConverter(value = "groupConverter")
```

and change my SelectManyMenu tag to include

```
converter="groupConverter"
```

then it works as expected.

Is this a bug in JSF/Primefaces?

I am using:
Primefaces 3.5
Tomcat 7

Thanks

Comment: In future JSF-related questions, it's wise to add the `[jsf]` tag.

Answer (score 2):

The converter will fail when the type behind `#{maintainMB.filteredLogicalGroups}` is a generic collection, such as `List<Group>`, instead of a plain array, such as `Group[]`.

The reason is simple: generic type information is only present during compiletime and completely absent during runtime. EL/reflection doesn't run during compiletime but only during runtime and all it sees is thus just a `List`. Without a converter, it'll assume it to hold items of the default type of `String`, the same as HTTP request parameters.

If you want to make use of `forClass`, then you'd need to change `List<Group>` property to a `Group[]` property.

```
private Group[] filteredLogicalGroups;
```

Otherwise, you really have to explicitly specify the converter.